# Hi, Iam working on .Net WebForms project and i had problems when i tried to publish the project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, webforms

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error c:\Users\enotes_svc\AppData\Local\Temp\2\WebSitePublish\enotes--2025862961\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\ClientStaff.aspx(11): error CS0433: The type 'servicenotes.ClientSelectAutoComplete' exists in both 'c:\Users\enotes_svc\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Temporary ASP.NET Files\enotes\f1db2339\6e2a5609\App_Web_eeafexvb.dll' and 'c:\Users\enotes_svc\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Temporary ASP.NET Files\enotes\f1db2339\6e2a5609\App_Web_3eh567o_.dll'
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error The type 'servicenotes.ClientSelectAutoComplete' exists in both 'c:\Users\enotes_svc\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Temporary ASP.NET Files\enotes\f1db2339\6e2a5609\App_Web_eeafexvb.dll' and 'c:\Users\enotes_svc\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Temporary ASP.NET Files\enotes\f1db2339\6e2a5609\App_Web_3eh567o_.dll' enotes  c:\Users\enotes_svc\AppData\Local\Temp\2\WebSitePublish\enotes--2025862961\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\ServiceNoteStaffing.aspx 76
I tryed to clean the temp data and rebuild
and i tryed to do this code :

Comment: Please share your .csproj file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.